# Vertically align divs for mobile view

Tags: html, css

I have 5 div side by side in the desktop view.
I have used "display:block-inline" to achieve this.

For my mobile view, I have used media query and set the display to "display: block" so that they align vertically in mobile devices.

However, when I switch to mobile view, the divs are aligning vertically one after the other, but I am losing the styling which is there in the desktop view. Like background color and text color.

I cannot understand why this is happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I have an obligation not to use Bootstrap

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #222222;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #F98900;
}

nav[role="sub"] ul {
  background-color: #525252;
}

nav[role="sub"] li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: #525252;
  color: #F98900;
}

nav[role="main"] ul {
  background-color: #222222;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.mml
/*manual margin to left */

{
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.dailystatus {
  color: #ABABA7;
  background-color: #343434;
}

.mpl {
  padding-left: 4em;
}

@media(max-width:500px) {
  .mpl {
    padding-left: 1em;
  }
  .mmt {
    margin-top: 1em;
  }
  .block2 {
    display: block;
  }
}

.width {
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mml">
  <p> Your task view all</p>
  <div class="width block dailystatus block2">
    <p>Follow Up 05:30pm</p>
    <p>Ashwin Kumar</p>
    <p>Brigade Group</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p>barbara.coolier@chance.name</p>
    <p>+91 8965238745</p>
    <p>City</p>
    <p>Bangalore</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no sea altera primis blandit, id nam cibo labitur. In iuvaret bonorum argumentum eum
    </p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="width block mml dailystatus block2">
    <p>Follow Up 05:30pm</p>
    <p>Ashwin Kumar</p>
    <p>Brigade Group</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p>barbara.coolier@chance.name</p>
    <p>+91 8965238745</p>
    <p>City</p>
    <p>Bangalore</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no sea altera primis blandit, id nam cibo labitur. In iuvaret bonorum argumentum eum
    </p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="width block mml dailystatus block2">
    <p>Follow Up 05:30pm</p>
    <p>Ashwin Kumar</p>
    <p>Brigade Group</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p>barbara.coolier@chance.name</p>
    <p>+91 8965238745</p>
    <p>City</p>
    <p>Bangalore</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no sea altera primis blandit, id nam cibo labitur. In iuvaret bonorum argumentum eum
    </p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="width block mml dailystatus block2">
    <p>Follow Up 05:30pm</p>
    <p>Ashwin Kumar</p>
    <p>Brigade Group</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p>barbara.coolier@chance.name</p>
    <p>+91 8965238745</p>
    <p>City</p>
    <p>Bangalore</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no sea altera primis blandit, id nam cibo labitur. In iuvaret bonorum argumentum eum
    </p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="width block mml dailystatus block2">
    <p>Follow Up 05:30pm</p>
    <p>Ashwin Kumar</p>
    <p>Brigade Group</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p>barbara.coolier@chance.name</p>
    <p>+91 8965238745</p>
    <p>City</p>
    <p>Bangalore</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no sea altera primis blandit, id nam cibo labitur. In iuvaret bonorum argumentum eum
    </p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to control the width of the divs so that they apply full width of the device in mobile view

Comment: If you could share your code (HTML and CSS) we may be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS code is completely off if you have posted full code, you haven't used any *list* items. Those styles would be only applied to list items. That being said I think you have posted half of the code so anyways;

I have done some edits see this code. When resized each one stacks on top.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .9rem;
  background-color: #343434;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: #525252;
  color: #F98900;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}


/* 1 column: 320px */

.autowide {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 98%;
}

.autowide img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 .75rem 0 0;
}

.autowide .module {
  background-color: #4c4b4b;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.autowide .module p {
  padding: .25rem .75rem;
}


/* 2 columns: 600px */

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .autowide .module {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2.564102564102564%;
    width: 48.717948717948715%;
  }
  .autowide .module:nth-child(2n+0) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}


/* 3 columns: 768px */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .autowide .module {
    width: 31.623931623931625%;
  }
  .autowide .module:nth-child(2n+0) {
    margin-right: 2.564102564102564%;
  }
  .autowide .module:nth-child(3n+0) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}


/* 4 columns: 992px and up */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .autowide .module {
    width: 23.076923076923077%;
  }
  .autowide .module:nth-child(3n+0) {
    margin-right: 2.564102564102564%;
  }
  .autowide .module:nth-child(4n+0) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="autowide">
  <div class="module">
    <p>Follow Up 05:30pm</p>
    <p>Ashwin Kumar</p>
    <p>Brigade Group</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p><a>barbara.coolier@chance.name</a></p>
    <p>+91 8965238745</p>
    <p>City</p>
    <p>Bangalore</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no sea altera primis blandit, id nam cibo labitur. In iuvaret bonorum argumentum eum
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="module">
    <p>Follow Up 05:30pm</p>
    <p>Ashwin Kumar</p>
    <p>Brigade Group</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p><a>barbara.coolier@chance.name</a></p>
    <p>+91 8965238745</p>
    <p>City</p>
    <p>Bangalore</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no sea altera primis blandit, id nam cibo labitur. In iuvaret bonorum argumentum eum
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="module">
    <p>Follow Up 05:30pm</p>
    <p>Ashwin Kumar</p>
    <p>Brigade Group</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p><a>barbara.coolier@chance.name</a></p>
    <p>+91 8965238745</p>
    <p>City</p>
    <p>Bangalore</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no sea altera primis blandit, id nam cibo labitur. In iuvaret bonorum argumentum eum
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="module">
    <p>Follow Up 05:30pm</p>
    <p>Ashwin Kumar</p>
    <p>Brigade Group</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p><a>barbara.coolier@chance.name</a></p>
    <p>+91 8965238745</p>
    <p>City</p>
    <p>Bangalore</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no sea altera primis blandit, id nam cibo labitur. In iuvaret bonorum argumentum eum
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="module">
    <p>Follow Up 05:30pm</p>
    <p>Ashwin Kumar</p>
    <p>Brigade Group</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p><a>barbara.coolier@chance.name</a></p>
    <p>+91 8965238745</p>
    <p>City</p>
    <p>Bangalore</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no sea altera primis blandit, id nam cibo labitur. In iuvaret bonorum argumentum eum
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified the CSS and using a flexbox. Inside the media query, the width is redefined to make it 100%.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dailystatus {
  color: #ABABA7;
  background-color: #343434;
}

.width {
  width: 15%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .width {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<p> Your task view all</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="width dailystatus">
    <p>Follow Up 05:30pm</p>
    <p>Ashwin Kumar</p>
    <p>Brigade Group</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p>barbara.coolier@chance.name</p>
    <p>+91 8965238745</p>
    <p>City</p>
    <p>Bangalore</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no sea altera primis blandit, id nam cibo labitur. In iuvaret bonorum argumentum eum
    </p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="width dailystatus">
    <p>Follow Up 05:30pm</p>
    <p>Ashwin Kumar</p>
    <p>Brigade Group</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p>barbara.coolier@chance.name</p>
    <p>+91 8965238745</p>
    <p>City</p>
    <p>Bangalore</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no sea altera primis blandit, id nam cibo labitur. In iuvaret bonorum argumentum eum
    </p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="width dailystatus">
    <p>Follow Up 05:30pm</p>
    <p>Ashwin Kumar</p>
    <p>Brigade Group</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p>barbara.coolier@chance.name</p>
    <p>+91 8965238745</p>
    <p>City</p>
    <p>Bangalore</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no sea altera primis blandit, id nam cibo labitur. In iuvaret bonorum argumentum eum
    </p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="width dailystatus">
    <p>Follow Up 05:30pm</p>
    <p>Ashwin Kumar</p>
    <p>Brigade Group</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p>barbara.coolier@chance.name</p>
    <p>+91 8965238745</p>
    <p>City</p>
    <p>Bangalore</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no sea altera primis blandit, id nam cibo labitur. In iuvaret bonorum argumentum eum
    </p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="width dailystatus">
    <p>Follow Up 05:30pm</p>
    <p>Ashwin Kumar</p>
    <p>Brigade Group</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p>barbara.coolier@chance.name</p>
    <p>+91 8965238745</p>
    <p>City</p>
    <p>Bangalore</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no sea altera primis blandit, id nam cibo labitur. In iuvaret bonorum argumentum eum
    </p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```